# How do I get a decent easy to use watermark from an image in Quantum?

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer

Our users need to be able to put a graphic watermark onto maps they create in the print composer. Currently we get them to georeference the image as a raster and then create a transparency. This is quite complex for some of my beginners. Anybody got any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

In print composer go Layout->Add Image. In picture options (in Item Properties tab) that will occur to the right, choose path to the image (raster or svg). In General Options (the same tab) choose the opacity value.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but that only seems to change the opacity of the background - how do I get it to change the opacity of the image itself?

Comment: @NeilBenny, I've never used this option so I'm not sure whether this is bug or not for it is 'opacity', not 'background opacity'. For me this slider do nothing if applied to the map for example (even background opacity stays the same), so the bug is highly likely to be here. I suppose, you don't have to create unique watermark for every map, so a handful of watermarks with different degrees of transparency will cover all your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You may also add the image, then going to `Item properties` > `Rendering` > `Blending mode` and choosing a different blending mode to that specific image: `Addition` and `Subtract` worked well to the kind of image and background I have.